# I had set the hostname in /etc/hosts , but when i run hostname in terminal , it displays

Tags: linux

The output below shows the hosts file data as well as the content when I run hostname command in terminal.

```
rohit@your_host_name:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    rohit

other lines....

rohit@your_host_name:~$ hostname
your_host_name.your_domain_name.com
```

Comment: You don't set your server's hostname in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: have you set the hostname in /etc/hostname and rebooted teh machine, or reset teh hostname internally with `sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname` ?

Answer (score 4):

The hosts file is not the place where you can change the hostname of your machine. You can use `hostname` to set a name. Check `man hostname`. For permanent changes, you can check config files like `/etc/hostname`, but this may differ from a distribution to another.